# Symfony Doctrine Collection get single value

Tags: arrays, symfony, foreach, collections, doctrine

I have two entities User and Product in a ManyToMany relation.
Inside a voter I would like to give delete permission on a Product if the User is among the $product->getUsers.
So far I managed to do things like this

```
foreach ($user->getProducts() as $userProduct) {
    foreach ($userProduct->getUsers() as $productUser) {
        if($productUser->getId() === $user->getId()) {
            return true;
                break;
        }
   }
}
```

The user variable is:

```
$user = $token->getUser();
```

and I check if it is:

```
    // if the user is anonymous, do not grant access
    if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        return false;
    }
```

Every User has a Collection of Products -> Every Product in this Collection has a Collection of Users.
I check if the id of the current authenticaded user ($user->getId()) is present among the ids of the Users Collection of the product with code:

```
if($productUser->getId() === $user->getId()) {
        return true;
            break;
    }
```

and I exit the loop. If not, access is denied.

Is there a better more elegant and efficient way to accomplish this task?
Any built -in Symfony method I should use for the purpose?

Comment: You're getting users products and then you're getting product users, which implies this check `$productUser->getId() === $user->getId()` will eventually return true, so your code snippet does not check anything at all

Comment: I suggest you to post the whole code

Comment: @LuninRoman My === has no meaning? Very likely I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Don't u think that if a user is related to product through many-to-many relationship, the product will always be related to the same exact user?

Comment: It feels like you are considering the problem from a wrong perspective, you should be comparing one single product users to currently logged user. Try to write tests first and work through the scenario

Comment: @LuninRoman ok. so if I get the id of the product to edit (or to delete) I could check if the current authenticated user is in the Users collection of that product. Anyway for accomplishing this task I should do one foreach loop (instead of two). User and Product are both Collections when it comes to relate them. Am I wrong?

Comment: No need for the loop. U can check it like so `if ($product->getUsers()->contains($user)) {...}`

Comment: @LuninRoman to perform this check I have to pass the current product id to be deleted (or edited) to the symfony voteOnAttribute function. Anyway the return statement for the 'PRODUCT_DELETE' (or 'PRODUCT_EDIT') case should be return ($product->getUsers()->contains($user))

Comment: @LuninRoman code updated. Do you agree. If you post your answer I will flag it as the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside the voter I avoid the double foreach loop like this (passing the product instance)

```
    class ProductVoter extends Voter
    {
        protected function supports($attribute, $subject) {
            return in_array($attribute, ['PRODUCT_EDIT', 'PRODUCT_DELETE'])
                && $subject instanceof \App\Entity\Product;
        }

        protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token)
        {
            $user = $token->getUser();

            // if the user is anonymous, do not grant access
            if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
                return false;
            }

            $product = $subject;

            // ... (check conditions and return true to grant permission) ...
            switch ($attribute) {
                case 'PRODUCT_EDIT':
                    // logic to determine if the user can EDIT
                    // return true or false
                    return $user === $product->getUsers();
                    break;
                case 'PRODUCT_DELETE':   
                    return $product->getId() === $user->getProducts()->first()->getId();
                    //@Lunin Roman version works too
//return $product->getUsers()->contains($user);
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently it has to be something like below:

```
class ProductVoter extends Voter
{
    const DELETE = 'PRODUCT_DELETE';
    const EDIT = 'PRODUCT_EDIT';

    protected function supports($attribute, $subject) 
    {
        return in_array($attribute, [self::EDIT, self::DELETE]) 
            && $subject instanceof Product;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();

        // if the user is anonymous, do not grant access
        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            return false;
        }

        $product = $subject;

        switch ($attribute) {
            case self::EDIT:
            case self::DELETE:
                return $this->productIsAssignedToUser($product, $user);
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function productIsAssignedToUser(Product $product, UserInterface $user): bool 
    {
        return $product->getUsers()->contains($user);    
    }
```

}